# How to set a custom value for records in a Report?

Tags: silverstripe

The code below is a custom report I'm putting together, using SilverStripe 3.1.

The Title and ClassName values are working fine, but though I can get the Status for each Page I'm not sure how to set the Status value against each Page in the DataList. How can I do that?

Once that's done, the Status column should be populated.

```
class PageListByType extends SS_Report {

    function title() {
        return 'Page List by Type';
    }

    function description() {
        return 'List all the pages in the site, along with their page type';
    }

    public function sourceRecords($params = array(), $sort = null, $limit = null) {
        $pages = Page::get()->sort($sort);
        foreach ($pages as $pagenum=>$page) {
            $flags = $page->getStatusFlags();
            if ($flags) {
                foreach ($flags as $status) {
//                    if (isset($pages[$pagenum]->Status)) die(array($pages[$pagenum]->Status, $status)); #detect multiple statuses; not sure if this will happen
                    /////////////////////////
                    // The following line needs fixing:
                    /////////////////////////
                    $pages[$pagenum]->Status = "{$status['text']} ({$status['title']})";
                }
            }
        }
//        die($pages->debug());
        return $pages;
    }

    public function columns() {
        return array(
            'Title' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.PageName', 'Page name'),
            'ClassName' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.ClassName', 'Page type'),
            'Status' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.Status', 'Status')
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit: Thanks @Turnerj for your answer! My final working code is as follows:**

```
class PageListByType extends SS_Report {

    function title() {
        return 'Page List by Type';
    }

    function description() {
        return 'List all the pages in the site, along with their page type';
    }

    public function sourceRecords($params = array(), $sort = null, $limit = null) {
        $pages = DataObject::get("SiteTree", "", "");
        return $pages;
    }

    public function columns() {
        return array(
            'Title' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.PageName', 'Page name'),
            'ClassName' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.ClassName', 'Page type'),
            'Status' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.Status', 'Status')
        );
    }
}
```

**and in Page.php:**

```
public function getStatus() {
    $flags = $this->getStatusFlags();
    $result = array();
    if ($flags) {
        foreach ($flags as $status) {
            $result[] = "{$status['text']} ({$status['title']})";
        }
    } else {
        $result[] = 'Published';
    }
    return implode(', ', $result);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a function called `getStatus` to the actual page that returns what you are generating in that foreach loop for the individual page? I would think that the report would then pick up the right data with the column `Status`.

Comment: @Turnerj creating that function successfully displays a value for the report when I make the function return a dummy value, however from within that function I don't get anything back from $this->getStatusFlags();  Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Hmmmm, not sure why that might be happening but I can look into that and get back to you with an answer. :)

Comment: Not sure why [`getStatusFlags`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-SiteTree.html#2628-2676) didn't work. The code for it doesn't seem to have any potential issues, try passing `false` to the first argument to skip the cache? (Not sure how expensive the lookup is without cache though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, I recreated the issue and found the solution.

Overall, my solution involves what I suggested in the comments about bringing the status fetching to the actual `Page` by adding a `getStatus` function.

I described essentially the following:

```
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->getStatusFlags();
}
```

This *technically* is correct, it will get the status flags but you are right, it doesn't display them in the report. This is due to this function returning an array which the report does not understand to render.

My solution is to change this function to return a string so with a few simple edits combining what you wrote with what I wrote, we get the following:

```
public function getStatus()
{
    $flags = $this->getStatusFlags();
    $result = array();
    if ($flags)
    {
        foreach ($flags as $status)
        {
            $result[] = "{$status['text']} ({$status['title']})";
        }
    }
    return implode(', ', $result);
}
```

I've got one unique twist on combining our code, I add each status to an array and [`implode` it back to a single string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). This can seem a little excessive, by default [`getStatusFlag` will return one key](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-SiteTree.html#2628-2676) in the array. If however you have a `DataExtension` that has the `updateStatusFlags` method, you could add additional keys to the result.

Basically, I would leave the `implode` handling in if in the future you do have code that messes with the status flags.

Now, you might be able to do something similar using the `$casting` property on the `Page` but given you were essentially adding this function just for the report, it was cleaner to just update it directly.

---

I did notice that the status flags array is actually empty if the page is published which means your report won't have anything next to published pages. If that is your intention, great!

If not, you could do another little alteration:

```
public function getStatus()
{
    $flags = $this->getStatusFlags();
    $result = array();
    if ($flags)
    {
        foreach ($flags as $status)
        {
            $result[] = "{$status['text']} ({$status['title']})";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result[] = 'Published (The page has been published)';
    }
    return implode(', ', $result);
}
```

The `if ($flags)` will evaluate to `false` when there are no current statuses (aka. the page is published) [due to automatic casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Comment: Thanks very much! I've put my final working code in the question. Presumably there's nothing special about the name "Status" so a getWhatever function could be added to populate a Whatever column in the report?

Comment: Pretty much. I used specifically "getStatus" vs "status" or "Status" for pure naming conventions with how Silverstripe describe but it all works the same. Not even just for reports, that works for GridField via the `$summary_fields` static property (eg. `array('WhateverMyFuncIs' => 'My Special Name')` ).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with an anonymous function inside columns()?

```
class PageListByType extends SS_Report {

  function title() {
      return 'Page List by Type';
  }

  function description() {
      return 'List all the pages in the site, along with their page type';
  }

  public function sourceRecords($params = array(), $sort = null, $limit = null) {
      return Page::get()->sort($sort);
  }

  public function columns() {
      return array(
          'Title' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.PageName', 'Page name'),
          'ClassName' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.ClassName', 'Page type'),
          'Status' => array(
             'title'=>_t('PageListByTypeReport.Status', 'Status'),
             'formatting' => function($value, $item) {
                $flags = $item->getStatusFlags();
                $status = '';
                if ($flags) {
                  foreach ($flags as $status) {
                    $status = "{$status['text']} ({$status['title']})";
                  }
                }
                return $status ? : _t('PageListByTypeReport.PagePublished', 'Page published');
             }
          )
      );
  }
}
```